# If column value is 1 then get same value for the following date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data like table A. I try to write a SQL code to change the Flag column value to 1 wherever the pervious month (column Date) Flag value is 1 for each ID.

```
 **Table A**
 ID      | Date      | Flag |
+--------+-----------+------+
| 1      | Jan 20    | 1    |
| 1      | Feb 20    | 0    |
| 1      | Mar 20    | 0    |  
| 2      | Jan 20    | 0    |
| 2      | Feb 20    | 1    |
| 2      | Mar 20    | 0    |
+--------+-----------+------+
```

I want results like this:

```
 ID      | Date      | Flag |
+--------+-----------+------+
| 1      | Jan 20    | 1    |
| 1      | Feb 20    | 1    |
| 1      | Mar 20    | 0    |  
| 2      | Jan 20    | 0    |
| 2      | Feb 20    | 1    |
| 2      | Mar 20    | 1    |
+--------+-----------+------+
```

I'd really appreciated if someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `select` you can do:

```
select t.*,
       (case when flag = 0 and lag(flag) over (partition by id order by date) = 1
             then 1
             else flag
        end) as imputed_flag          
from t;
```

If you want to update the flag, you can use:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, 
             lag(flag) over (partition by id order by date) as prev_flag
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set flag = 1
    where prev_flag = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks so much, your answer is very clear. what if I want to have 1 imputed_flag value if flag value is 1 during last 4 months?

Comment: @Mike . . . That would be a different question and should be asked as a *new* question.

Comment: @Mike . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?  It does answer your question; it was the first answer, and it is probably the. most efficient code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update the record then use `exists` as follows:

```
Update your_table t
   Set t.flag = 1
 Where t.flag = 0 
   And exists 
      (Select 1 from your_table tt
        Where t.id = tt.id
          And DATEADD(month, -1, tt.date) = t.date
          And tt.flag = 1)
```